# Post size limit with writeFile() in dropbox-js Client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, dropbox

I am trying to upload big files to Dropbox with the [Unofficial Javascript Library](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js) in a simple NodeJS shell app.

```
fs.readFile(file_local, function(error, data) {
    client.writeFile(file_dbox, data, function(error, stat) {
        if (error) {
            return handleError(error);
        }
    }
}
```

I see a limit of sending between 300mb and 350mb, Dropbox returns the follwing error :

> Dropbox API error 413 from POST

Is there anyway to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

For large files, you should use chunked a.k.a resumable uploads:

http://coffeedoc.info/github/dropbox/dropbox-js/master/classes/Dropbox/Client.html#resumableUploadStep-instance
http://coffeedoc.info/github/dropbox/dropbox-js/master/classes/Dropbox/Client.html#resumableUploadFinish-instance

These methods let you upload a file in smaller pieces so that any individual request is less likely to fail.

Comment: Thank you, i search for resumableUploadStep and i found this example : https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/issues/112